Can xsdata deep parse AnyElements?
I can currently successfully parse XML out of a schema that, at some level has wildcard element.
When I load the top level documents with
obj = XmlParser.parse(tree, MyClass)
assert isinstance(obj.some_path.any_element, AnyElement)
is true and inspecting its' properties, maps to a schema for which xsdata generated also the respective classes, say MyWildCardClass1
My question is if there is any way that I can use xsdata to bind obj.some_path.any_element to my MyWildCardClass1, or is the only solution really to parse the xml again at the right level of the hierarcy, i.e.
XmlParser.parse(tree.find(".//somepath"), MyWildCardClass1)
?
